# Laravel Nova access related model id from resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Having:

```
Listing:
id
user_id
...


ListingTranslation:
id
listing_id
language_id
...

Language
id
iso_code
...

One to Many Relationship between Listing and ListingtTranslation

Listing hasMany ListingTranslation
ListingTranslation belongsTo Listing

One to Many Relationship between Language and ListingTranslation

Language hasMany ListingTranslation
ListingTranslation belongsTo Language
```

I am looking for a way to access `listing_id` from `ListingTranslation` Resource.

The related Listing field is declared in `ListingTranslation Resource`:

```
BelongsTo::make(__('Listing'), 'listing', 'App\Nova\Listing'),
```

The aim is to be able to have a select field in `Listing Translation Resource` with the available languages so a `Listing` can have only One `ListingTranslation` for available `Language`. The Language select field will show a validation error if the user selects a Language that has already a created `ListingTranslation` for that particular `Language`.

The relationship is eager loaded in my `ListingTranslation` resource:

```
public static $with = [
    'listing'
];
```

I can use it in title and subtitle methods. However, I cannot access it from the fields method:

```
BelongsTo::make(__('Language'), 'language', 'App\Nova\Language')
                ->rules("unique:listing_translations,language_id,NULL,id,listing_id,{$this->listing->id}"),
```

Comment: make a custom rule and access request('listing') for a BelongsTo / listing